# Angular 9 - trackBy template type checking angular

Tags: angular, angular9

I have a simple trackBy statement which was no prob until ng9.

```
<div *ngFor="let s of skills; trackBy: s?.id">
  <app-skill [skill]="s"></app-skill>
</div>
```

Now with template type checking the compiler complains that: Property 's' does not exist on type 'SkillsListComponent' - which is true - because it was defined inline as expression. This compilation error also is no show stopper as the code runs ... just want to have a neat code base. Does anybody know how to write this in a ng9 friendly way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the **[documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby)** you can call a method in `trackBy`

So you can define method which will return the id

```
trackByItems(index: number, skill: {id: number}): number {
   return skill.id;
}
```

> I specified the type there like this since I don't know what type you are using

And in HTML just call it

```
<div *ngFor="let s of skills; trackBy: trackByItems">
  <app-skill [skill]="s"></app-skill>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess no more "complex" inline expressions

Comment: Probably yes because now it look that you can only call a method there which is probably better.